# How can I run an Async IO operation that doesn't block the main thread but throws an exception in the main thread if it fails?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm investigating Cats to accomplish the above. I tried writing the below example to

1. Run an IO operation that doesn't block the main thread
2. Throws an exception in the main thread if it fails

```
import cats.effect.{IO, Async}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

val apiCall = Future.successful("I come from the Future!")

val ioa: IO[String] =
  Async[IO].async { cb =>
    import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    throw new RuntimeException

    apiCall.onComplete {
      case Success(value) => cb(Right(value))
      case Failure(error) => cb(Left(error))
    }
 }

ioa.unsafeRunAsync(result => result match {
    case Left(result) => throw result
    case Right(_) =>
})
```

However it seems to fail at both of those things. It blocks the main thread and only throws an exception in the child thread. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
val longRunningOperation: IO[Unit] = ...
val app: IO[Unit] = ...

val program: IO[Unit] =
  IO.racePair(app, longRunningOperation).flatMap {
    case Left((_, fiberLongRunning)) =>  fiberLongRunning.cancel.void
    case Right((fiberApp, _)) => fiberApp.join.void
  }

override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
  program.as(ExitCode.Success)
```

`racePair` will run two **IOs** concurrently and in case one of the two fails, then it will `cancel` the other one.
Now, if the `longRunningOperation` finishes without error, then er wait for the `app`; But, if the `app` is the one that finished first, then I decided to `cancel` the `longRunningOperation` *(you can, of course, change that)*.

---

Thanks to Adam Rosien for pointing out that if you want to `join` in both cases then best would be:

```
val program: IO[Unit] = (app, longRunningOperation).parTupled.void
```

---

*You can see the code running and play with it [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/QhlIChKTSNCx91zrmqiWMw/5)*